# Discriminated union doesn't work for undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react component which has two props `required` and `fallback` , the type definition for it's props is as following :

```
type Props = 
| {
   required? : true | undefined,
   fallback : React.ReactNode
}
| {
   required? : false,
   fallback? : React.ReactNode
}
```

My intention is to make `fallback` required if `required` prop is `true` or `undefined` , it works for  `required = true` but not `required = undefined`.

```
<FancyComponent required={true} /> //typescript gives error for this, which is what I expect

<FancyComponent /> //here required is undefined but typescript does not gives any error.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Leaving it empty produces this error `Property 'required' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ required: false; fallback?: ReactNode; }'`

Comment: checkout this sand-box https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ptk48v?file=components/session/session.tsx
`/components/session/session.tsx`
and the code for it's usage is here `pages/index.tsx`

Comment: @TobiasS. You get error for `required` prop , it was my mistake. Updated the question, check it out again please.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark (`?`) after `required` means that it's an optional prop, meaning that *both* types match the `undefined` case. You should remove the `?`s after `required` in the false case:

```
type Props = 
| {
   required?: true,
   fallback: React.ReactNode
}
| {
   required: false,
   fallback?: React.ReactNode
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but doing this I have to provide a value for required itself which is not what i want.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili how about now?

Comment: No luck.............!